# On screen resolution-

Tags: resolution, screen

How do I get the screen resolution down to where I can set the screen resolution and click the apply icon? I can't get the screen resolution page to move up and down to click the icon that is under the bottom bar at the bottom of the screen to click it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you edit your question to provide a little bit more information on your setup, including what version of Ubuntu you are using and which screen resolutions you are starting from and trying to switch to? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `xrandr` to change the screen resolution. `xrandr -s 1280x1024` in a terminal should change the resolution to 1280 by 1024, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can hold down alt then click-drag the window you need to move around.

Works on KDE, not sure how the other DE's will handle it though.

Comment: This works for me under Unity.

Comment: Alt then click on active window and drag works for me in unity too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works to use the workspace below it. Than you can see the second half of the window. Hope it works for you aswell.

It's just a solution to press the apply button...

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you add more info to your answer like one or two screenshots(you can upload them to imgur.com) and a more detailed how to.

Comment: I use minesweeper as example for a screen what doesn't fit... hope it's helpfull

http://i.imgur.com/1wCs7Tr.png?1